# Get page type to display content

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-development, customization

I have some checkboxes to select where can I display my plugin and I save in db in this format:

Show popup in this pages:

x Article (Public)

x Pages (Public)

x File (Public)

x Revisions (Not public)

Those settings I save in db in this format:
So if i CHECKED to show popup in post and pages i have

```
a:2:{i:0;s:4:"post";i:1;s:4:"page";}
```

How to add some filters or to check when to display content? Something like:

```
if(in_array(current_page, my_array_with_accepted_pages)) show something
```

or just add some filters and the plugin will now where to display the content.

Comment: From your question I am fuzzy on how your data is stored and where precisely you want to display it. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I updated the post, can you see if you understand?